# using System.Linq; in .net

Tags: .net, linq

I want to return the latest poll order by publish_at

some thing like :

```
return  db.Polls.Where(p => p.status.Equals(PollStatus.Active))
                .OrderByDescending(d => d.publish_at)
                .Take(1);
```

Unfortunately, this does not work. How can I get just the most recent result, and not every result?

Comment: not getting you what is your question

Comment: What happens when the code you posted executes?

Comment: Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints and then edit your question accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have with your current code is an *Enumerable* that will iterate over exactly one item. You don't yet have the item itself.

Instead of `.Take(1)`, try using `.First()` or `.Single()`, or perhaps `.FirstOrDefault()` or `.SingleOrDefault()`. It's worth your time to lookup and read the documentation on each of those.

Answer (score 0):

here my post to get last n record that will help you if you want to get last inserted record

[Get Last n Records using Linq to SQL](http://pranayamr.blogspot.in/2012/05/get-last-n-records-using-linq-to-sql.html)

Easy way to get last recrod

```
var qry = db.ObjectCollection
                     .Where(m => m.<field> == data)
                     .OrderByDescending(m => m.<field>)
                     .FirstOrDefault();
```

if you want last n record

```
var qry = db.ObjectCollection
                     .Where(m => m.<field> == data)
                     .OrderByDescending(m => m.<field>)
                     .Take(n);
```